# Making a scalable setter

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a constructor that looks something like this:

```
data FilterType 
  = OwnerId
  | OwnerIdReportType
  | ReportTypeProductType

filterParams = FilterParams
  { filterType :: FilterType
  , ownerId :: Maybe Id
  , productType :: Maybe ProductType
  , reportType :: Maybe ReportType
  }
```

Then when I set the filter params, I'm doing it like this, so I only fetch the data that I need:

```
defaultFilterParams =
  { filterType = OwnerId
  , ownerId = Nothing
  , productType = Nothing
  , reportType = Nothing
  }

mkFilterParams :: FilterType -> Id -> IO FilterParams
mkFilterParams OwnerId reportId = do
  ownerId <- getOwnerId reportId
  defaultFilterParams { ownerId }
mkFilterParams ReportTypeProductType reportId = do
  reportType <- getReportType reportId
  productType <- getProductType reportId
  defaultFilterParams
    { filterType = ReportTypeProductType
    , productType
    , reportType
    }
-- etc
```

Obviously as more FilterTypes get added, `mkFilterParams` starts to contain a lot of repeated code. Is there a more efficient/scalable way to implement this? I've been staring at it for too long to be able to see a new way.

Comment: Wait, so does each `FilterType` have the same parameters (that's the way your data types are structured)?  I'm not really sure what the pattern is that you would like to abstract away, partially because this code is not valid.  Can you write some *working* code with a small number of `FilterType`s?  (This can be a good place to start, and clarify with yourself exactly what you need.)

Comment: I assume you want to do something like `mkFilterParams reportId filterId = case filterId of ...` or `mkFilterParams reportId = go where go ...` or (with LambdaCase) `mkFilterParams reportId = \case ...`

Comment: @luqui Aside from a typo, what is invalid about this? It does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My other answer discusses a very simple solution that is Haskell2010; this has the advantage of being easy to understand and easy to use. But it does have a funny duplication of constructor names. In this answer I will give a short description of how to use GADTs to avoid that problem. GADTs give us a way to connect term constructors with the type-level. So:

```
data FilterType a where
    Owner :: FilterType Id
    Product :: FilterType ProductType
    ReportProduct :: FilterType (ReportType, ProductType)
```

Then we can return different information for each type of filter:

```
mkFilter :: FilterType a -> ReportId -> IO a
mkFilter Owner = getOwnerId
mkFilter Product = getProductId
mkFilter ReportProduct = \reportId -> (,) <$> getReportType reportId
                                          <*> getProductType reportId
```

Presumably to use one of these we would need to bundle together a `FilterType a` and an `a`; e.g. perhaps you would have a function with a type like this one:

```
filterMatches :: FilterType a -> a -> Record -> Bool
```

Such a bundle might even be worth formalizing in its own existential type:

```
data Filter where Filter :: FilterType a -> a -> Filter
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
data FilterType = OwnerT | ProductT | ReportProductT
data Filter
    = Owner Id
    | Product ProductType
    | ReportProduct ReportType ProductType

mkFilter :: FilterType -> ReportId -> IO Filter
mkFilter ty reportId = case ty of
    OwnerT -> Owner <$> getOwnerId reportId
    ProductT -> Product <$> getProductType reportId
    ReportProductT -> ReportProduct <$> getReportType reportId
                                    <*> getProductType reportId
```

If the repeated `reportId` bothers you, you could consider using a type like:

```
mkFilter :: FilterType -> ReaderT ReportId IO Filter
```

This would probably feel cleanest if you then also modified `getOwnerId`, `getReportType`, and `getProductType` to use `ReaderT`.